# Website visitor count is not working on server(cloud window server). How do fix it?

Tags: asp.net

Deal All, I have a problem in asp.net publish file is running on server.The record of website visitor count is not working on server.But it work smoothly on my local IIS server.How do I fix it?
It is code in Global.asax.cs

```
 private static int totalNumberOfUsers = 0;
 protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {   
  //Code that run on application start up
    Application["NumberofVisitors"] = 0;          
    totalNumberOfUsers = 0;
 }
 protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {   
  //Code that run on a new session is started
  Application.Lock();
  totalNumberOfUsers = (int)Application["NumberofVisitors"] + 1;                 
  Application.UnLock();
 }
 protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  Application.Lock();          
  totalNumberOfUsers -= 1;
  Application.UnLock();
 }
public static int TotalNumberOfUsers { get { return totalNumberOfUsers; }     }
```

It is view.aspx

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblVisitorRecord" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" style="font-size:medium;">                                
                        </asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
```

It is code behind of view.aspx

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
    int totalNumberOfUsers = Global.TotalNumberOfUsers;
    lblVisitorRecord.Text = "Visitors : " + totalNumberOfUsers;
    if (!IsPostBack)
     {

     }    
  }
```

It is session time out in web.config

```
 <sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"sqlConnectionString="MainDB" cookieless="false" timeout="40" />
```

Comment: totalNuberOfUsers will always be set to 1 since you never increment Application["NumberofVisitors"]. 0 + 1 is always 1... Weird logic anyway, you don't need locking/unlocking to change value of shared variable, seems the code you shared is not complete?

Comment: Yeah!.It code is run smoothly on my local IIS server.The totalNumberofUsers is already increased. But it not increased in window server.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already declared `totalNumberOfUsers` as `static` you don't need `Application["NumberofVisitors"]`. You can simply increase or decrease value of `totalNumberOfUsers` as below.

```
private static int totalNumberOfUsers = 0;
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code that run on application start up
    totalNumberOfUsers = 0;
}
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code that run on a new session is started
    totalNumberOfUsers++;
}
protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    totalNumberOfUsers--;
}
public static int TotalNumberOfUsers { get { return totalNumberOfUsers; } }
```

Comment: Yes,I will test with your code.Thank you for your answer.